# Exterior penalty function method

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex, non-convex

I am trying to implement an exterior penalty function method for minimizing the below problem.

min f(x)=100*(x(2)-x(1)^2)^2+(1-x(1))^2

s.t, x(1)+2x(2)<=1

2x(1)+x(2)=1

First of all, I have found the minimum using `fmincon`, which the answer is `x`: `array([ 0.4149,  0.1701])` and `f(x)=0.34`.

Then I am trying to find the minimum using my implementation of exterior penalty function method.
I am using this penalty function:

F(x,a)=f(x)+a*(x(1)+2*x(2)-1)^2+a*(2*x(1)+x(2)-1)^2

with start point `x_0=[1,1]`, `a=10` (in each iteration a= a^2) , which gives me `x`: `array([ 0.3333,  0.3333])` and `f(x)=5.3`.

Where is the mistake in my implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm solves the following *equality* constrained problem!

minimize f(x)=100*(x(2)-x(1)^2)^2+(1-x(1))^2

subject to x(1)+2x(2)=1
           2x(1)+x(2)=1

and `fmincon` (correctly) solved the original problem (with one inequality and one equality constraint).